# How to pass parameter to NewForm.aspx for SPO list

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I'm using SharePoint Online Modern UI.
I placed a hyperlink in the list and open another list of NewForm from that link.
I wish I could pass parameters and change the form contents dynamically at that time.
Is that possible?
I am very grateful for any ideas.

Comment: not possible using out of the box capabilities of SharePoint online modern experience

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your form with a Power App.

Power Apps can read parameters passed to it via URL. Simple add your parameter at the end of the Power App URL like so:

?CustomParameter=777

To consume parameters passed in App URL, use Param function as Param(“parametername”).